Extracting All Sentinel-2 L2A Bands as GeoTIFF via SentinelHub API?
I want to extract a dataset from Sentinel-2, using the access provided by SentinelHub.
Till now I have the following code, which is derived from this documentation, and in which basically there are 5 main things specified:

Bands (B02, B03 & B04 for RGB output)
Satellite source (Sentinel-2 L2A in this case)
Mime type (.png file format)
Resolution (I want 10 m/pixel)
Time interval

pip install ipywidgets

import datetime
import os
import getpass
import random
import shutil

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

from sentinelhub import (
    SHConfig,
    CRS,
    BBox,
    DataCollection,
    DownloadRequest,
    MimeType,
    MosaickingOrder,
    SentinelHubDownloadClient,
    SentinelHubRequest,
    bbox_to_dimensions,
)

from utils import plot_image

config = SHConfig()
config.sh_client_id = getpass.getpass("Enter your SentinelHub client id")
config.sh_client_secret = getpass.getpass("Enter your SentinelHub client secret")
config.sh_token_url = "https://identity.dataspace.copernicus.eu/auth/realms/CDSE/protocol/openid-connect/token"
config.sh_base_url = "https://sh.dataspace.copernicus.eu"

def get_true_color_request(time_interval, bbox, size, config):

    evalscript_true_color = """
    //VERSION=3

    function setup() {
        return {
            input: [{
                bands: ["B02", "B03", "B04"]
            }],
            output: {
                bands: 3
            }
        };
    }

    function evaluatePixel(sample) {
        return [sample.B04, sample.B03, sample.B02];
    }
     """
    return SentinelHubRequest(
        evalscript=evalscript_true_color,
        input_data=[
            SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
                data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L2A.define_from(
                    "s2l2a", service_url=config.sh_base_url
                ),
                time_interval=time_interval,
                mosaicking_order=MosaickingOrder.LEAST_CC
            )
        ],
        responses=[SentinelHubRequest.output_response("default", MimeType.PNG)],
        bbox=bbox,
        size=size,
        config=config,
    )

def processing(locations, config):
    resolution = 10 # Meters per pixel

    start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 31)
    n_chunks = 16
    tdelta = (end - start) / n_chunks
    edges = [(start + i * tdelta).date().isoformat() for i in range(n_chunks)]
    slots = [(edges[i], edges[i + 1]) for i in range(len(edges) - 1)]

    brightness_factor = 2.5

    for loc_idx, coords in enumerate(locations):
        print(f"Processing location {loc_idx + 1}/{len(locations)}")

        bbox = BBox(bbox=coords, crs=CRS.WGS84)
        size = bbox_to_dimensions(bbox, resolution=resolution)

        list_of_requests = [
            get_true_color_request(slot, bbox, size, config)
            for slot in slots
        ]
        list_of_requests = [request.download_list[0] for request in list_of_requests]

        data = SentinelHubDownloadClient(config=config).download(
            list_of_requests, max_threads=5
        )

        for idx, image in enumerate(data):
            img = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
            enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
            brightened_image = enhancer.enhance(brightness_factor)
            image_path = f'imagepath/_{loc_idx}_{idx}.png'
            brightened_image.save(image_path)

        print(f"Processing of location {loc_idx + 1}/{len(locations)} completed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    locations = [
        (136.643143,34.762601,136.867676,34.943987),

    ]

    processing(locations, config)

I want to be able to have a GeoTiff output, where all bands of Sentinel-2 L2A will be displayed seperately, for further pre-processing, resampling and custom stacking.
How can I achieve that? Any help is appreciated.
